# Difference between "call it the night" and "call it a night"

Tags: difference, articles, idioms

What difference has "call it the night" and "call it a night"?

According to the google search the both expressions are correct.

**call it the night**: 20,800,000 hits
**call it a night**: 9,150,000 hits

Maybe the meaning are same?

Comment: 'Call it a night' is an idiom. 'Call it the night' is not an idiom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **[COCA corpus](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/)** has 95 results for "call it a night" and only 1 for "call it the night", and that single result is:

> ..if our language is afflicted by a hole right at its center. Let's call it **the** night of language, the sleep of language.

You see, the meaning is not the same. In "[call it **a** night](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/call_it_a_night)" you do not specify the "night" too much, you only wish to say:

> What we have on our hands is *a completed night*, now the only thing left to do is to go to bed.

On the other hand, when you use **the** you mean a night specific enough to take the definite article. In such a situation, I would think that the "night" has been previously mentioned by you, or I will await some "specifying information" in the sentence. In the COCA example, the author refers to some specific period in time when "language sleeps". The author uses an "of-phrase", and this makes the word "night" more definite.

---

Here's [a nice foray](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/call+it+a+day) into the etymology of **call it a day**, kudos to *[Man From India](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/3463/man-from-india)* (see his comments below my post):

> Stop a particular activity for the rest of the day, as in *It's past five o'clock so let's call it a day*. Similarly, *call it a night* means "to stop something for the rest of the night," as in *One more hand of bridge and then let's call it a night*. The original phrase was **call it half a day**, first recorded in 1838, which referred to leaving one's place of employment before the work day was over. The first recorded use of *call it a day* was in 1919, and of *call it a night* in 1938. (*The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms by Christine Ammer.*)

Comment: Copperkettle, does "call it a night" has anything to do with "call it a day"? I mean the set phrase is "call it a day", I think "call it a night" is just a variant of the set phrase, written along the same line.

Comment: @Man_From_India - my guess is that these phrases are almost synonymous. "A night" phrase probably is used for moments that are "further into the night". Maybe when you finish your day work it's "time to call it a day", and then you finish your partying afterwards, it's "time to call it a night".

Comment: Not always true. If someone wants to retire, he can say *it's time for me to call it a day*. So we can say "call it a day" anytime regardless of the time of the day or night :) (in my opinion).

Comment: @Man_From_India - what I meant is that probably the "night" phrase is used more often in moments more advanced in time, or after you've finished doing some "night-time" activity. I did not mean to say that "call it a day" is only applicable before some timepoint, and "call it a night" only after that timepoint.

Comment: @Man_From_India - but I'm not very certain.

Comment: I also believe the same in case of that "night" one :)

Comment: This explains. "call it a day" can mean a day's work, or may mean "to stop doing what one was doing regardless of the time". This links also talks about "call it a night" http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/call+it+a+day

Comment: No one will say "Call it a night" in the daytime. Unless it is 6am and folks have been working at some activity all night long and until the morning. Even then the aptness of saying 'call it a night' might be commented upon. *It's--what?! 6am?!--time to call it a night, or I mean, call it a day, or just call it time to go home (or to bed).*